# Is .data thread safe?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm

My asm function works fine if its only  one thread, but If try to use multi threading it makes the image almost fine, but there are some errors. I made sure that I push and pop registers that I use and I almost run out of ideas. My last idea is that things that I use and change in .data are same for both threads and maybe thats why image doesnt get processed the right way?
The c++ code calling asm function and creating threads:

```
void prepareThreads(Sepia& ProcAdd, const HINSTANCE& hinstLib, 
    BOOL& fRunTimeLinkSuccess, int32& bytesPerPixel, const int32& width,
    const int32& height, byte* pixels, int thread)
{
    ProcAdd = (Sepia)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "MyProc1");
    if (NULL != ProcAdd)
    {
        fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
        int threadsAmount = 4;
        int sizeOfSubArray = (bytesPerPixel * width * height) / threadsAmount;
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        for (int i = 0; i < threadsAmount; i++) {

            threads.push_back(std::thread(ProcAdd, pixels + i * sizeOfSubArray, sizeOfSubArray, bytesPerPixel));
        }
        for (auto& th : threads) {
            th.join();
        }

    }
}
```

Start of asm procedure, in rbx i put pointer to array of bytes, in rcx I put number of pixels.

```
.data
vec1 real4 0.393, 0.769, 0.189, 0.0
vec2 real4 0.349, 0.686, 0.168, 0.0
vec3 real4  0.272, 0.534, 0.131, 0.0
vecReal real4 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
vecResult real4 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
vecMaxBytes dword 255, 255, 255, 255 
masks db 0, 4, 8, 12, 12 dup (-1)

.code
MyProc1 proc var1:QWORD, var2:WORD, jmpAddress:WORD
push rdx;
push rax
push rcx
push rbp
push rdi
push rsi
push rbx

mov rbx,RCX
mov rcx,RDX
mov rsi, 0
```

Comment: You need to implement the equivalent of an atomic read | modify | write to keep the threads from stepping on each other's data.

Comment: If multiple threads concurrently modify the same data, this is going to lead to race conditions.  Apply synchronisation or use atomic operations.

Comment: Or depending on your algorithm have separate .data regions for each thread.

Comment: `.data` is static storage shared by all threads, just like C++ globals or `static` vars.  Thread safety depends on the code you use to read/write it.  It certainly doesn't do anything magical if you use the same storage for different things in different threads!!  This is assembly language so it's up to you to write asm that works like `std::atomic<T>`  would compile, if that's what you want.  (`lock cmpxchg` if you want an atomic RMW of FP data, or if your CPU supports it, Intel TSX transactional memory.)

Comment: It looks super weird to have `jmpAddress:WORD` - addresses are normally qword in x86-64.  Unless that's not literally an address, but an array index for some kind of jump in your algorithm, not something that will update RIP.